# Getting the newly added AutoID of MySQL using VBA in MS Access

Tags: mysql, vba, ms-access, primary-key

I have a MS Access app with a MySQL database. I have tried numerous ways from Stack Overflow but can't get the primary key of a newly added row.

I have tried everything I can find with no luck.

```
    Set pxRST = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * from tblPatients WHERE dispenseID = " & oPxID & " AND ChemistID = " & chemID, dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)
    if pxrst.eof then
    pxRST.AddNew
    pxRST("dispenseid") = oPxID
    pxRST("chemistID") = chemID
    pxRST("firstname") = firstName
    pxRST("lastname") = lastName
    pxRST("address") = Address
    pxRST("postcode") = postcode
    pxRST("phonenumber") = phonenumber
    pxRST.Update
    pxRST.Bookmark = pxRST.LastModified
    gPxID = pxRST!PatientID
    Debug.Print gPxID

end if
```

This gave a "record is deleted" error

I have also tried using one that had

```
gPxID  = currentdb.openrecordset("SELECT @@identity").value(0)
```

This just game me 0 as a figure

I did go into MYSQL workbench and try

```
INSERT INTO tblpatients
SELECT @@IDENTITY
```

and I did get a new record's ID.

So I've tried hard and got so far but I just can't figure it out from here and how to get this working in VBA.

I'm currently working on using QueryDefs, but I'm very new to this and haven't really got there I don't think.

```
Dim qdf2 As DAO.QueryDef

strSQL = "INSERT INTO tblPatients (dispenseid,chemistID,firstname,lastname,address,postcode,phonenumber) " & _
            "VALUES (" & oPxID & "," & chemID & ",'" & firstName & "','" & lastName & "','" & Address & "','" & postcode & "','" & phonenumber & "' )"

    Set qdf2 = db.QueryDefs("quGetPxDetails")
    With qdf2
    .SQL = strSQL
    .Connect = oCon
    qdf2.Execute

    End With
```

Comment: After [rtfm](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/), read [Optimizing Microsoft Office Access Applications Linked to SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2005/administrator/bb188204(v=sql.90)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) to understand how the connection ODBC works (even article is on SQL Server it applies to MySQL or any other RDBMS in most parts).

Comment: THanks @ComputerVersteher for the response.  As mentioned, I have spent numerous hours on this now hence turning for help.  I have had a browse through what you sent as links but still haven't found how to solve my problem.  If you do know how to do it, would you mind please letting me know where I am going wrong.

Comment: Don't browser through the links **read and understand** (at least try)! I bet, your table is missing a proper timestamp as the docs told you, didn't activate`return matched rows instead of affected`option in connection, or you missed the PK on linking. That causes your #deleted error! The ms link should have provided info that on ODBC queries get rewriten on DAO/JET besides Passthrough-Queries, that's why`Select @@Identity`fails, but you can't rely on it with MySQL (again the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-usagenotes-functionality-last-insert-id.html)

Comment: Similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/q/52001604/9439330

Comment: Thanks again for responding @ComputerVersteher.  The table has a timestamp that is working.
You are correct, i did not have RETURN MATCHED as ticked in the ODBC and I thought this was going to fix it, but it is still not working.
I ahve already tried that link you supplied just then and tried the suggested code as per the bottom relating to access, it also returned nothing.

Comment: Answers on SO link return nothing? Then you do sth wrong ;) Provide ODBC driver version, and DSN connection string! All other usual operations like inserts, updates and selects no issues? No`another user has modified the data` warnings? Try ADODB instead of DAO.

Comment: OK so i "think" the issue was that I was not running the insert query as a passthrough even if i ran the identity as one.  I have added my my working answer which in the end was your link as well as info from @user2834566

Comment: @ComputerVersteher: regarding your edit, please do not format proper nouns as code. Software names should just have correct case observed, but they are not themselves code. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my answer comes from both ComputerVersteher and User2834566 info.

I had to run two queries, both as passthrough and running on the same db instance to make sure it returned the right value:

```
Dim strSQL As String
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset


strSQL = "INSERT INTO medstome_masterdb.tblChemists (chemName) VALUES ('newchem')"
strGETID = "SELECT @@IDENTITY"


Set db = CurrentDb

    With db
        Set qdf = db.CreateQueryDef("")
            With qdf
                .ReturnsRecords = False
                .Connect = oCon
                .SQL = strSQL
                .Execute
            End With

            With qdf
                .ReturnsRecords = True
                .Connect = oCon
                .SQL = strGETID
                Set rst = .OpenRecordset(dbOpenSnapshot)
                gPxID = rst(0)
                Debug.Print gPxID
            End With
    End With
```

This works perfectly!
Thanks to the guys responding and helping

Answer (score 0):

It rather depend upon whether your `tblPatients` has an auto increment primary key or not.
If it does then you should not be assigning it a value manually, ie your

```
INSERT INTO tblPatients (dispenseid,chemistID,firstname,lastname,address,postcode,phonenumber) " & _
            "VALUES (" & oPxID & "," & chemID & ",'" & firstName & "','" & lastName & "','" & Address & "','" & postcode & "','" & phonenumber & "' )"
```

is not inserting anything into the PK.

Lets assume that you do have a column in tblPatients called 
`PatientID` of type `int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT`,

Now, after you insert a new record you can get back the id of that inserted record using the function

```
LAST_INSERT_ID()
```

so

```
Select  LAST_INSERT_ID() as my_last_pk;
```

would return the PK of the record you just inserted in a column called `my_last_pk`.

Note that this is session specific so if you and someone else both insert a new record at more or less the same time you would each get back your own inserted PK.

Comment: `LAST_INSERT_ID()`fails on DAO without explicit using a passthrough query.

Comment: Then I'm afraid it is something to do with your DAO  setup as last_insert_id() is a perfectly valid internal command in MySQL. What Database Management tool are you using SQLYog, PhPMyAdmin? Try doing and insert and then a `Select  LAST_INSERT_ID()` in that . it will work OK

Comment: Seems like you missed OP's initial statement (of course it's unclear, I'll edit). We use`Ms Access`as a frontend to MySQL via ODBC, so its MDAC/Jet engine parses sql before exec, without passthrough option (see my link in first comment on question).